# Why do Env variables like signer_account_id cause error: ProhibitedInView?

Tags: smartcontracts, nearprotocol

I'm getting a ProhibitedInView error for a simple view function that does the following

```
export function getInfo(): Info {
   const caller = context.sender
   return infos.getSome(caller)
}
```

and realised that it's because of the `context.sender` call.

My assumption/understanding is that as long as a tx doesn't change the state, they can be considered ViewFunctions.

I found a warning against this on the [Potential Gotchas](https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/contracts/as/intro#view-and-change-functions), but why do the following functions cause view functions to fail? What does "binding methods that are exposed from nearcore" mean?

- signer_account_id
- signer_account_pk
- predecessor_account_id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the context of a `view` functions, there is no such thing as:

- `signer_account_id`
- `signer_account_pk`
- `predecessor_account_id`

It is not required to sign any message to run a view function, and moreover it is not allowed. It is more like inspecting a contract anonymously, nothing should be paid for that, and the result is independent from the caller. Because of this there is no `signer_account_id` and `signer_account_pk`.

On the other hand, it is not possible to make a cross-contract call, if you are initiating this call in view mode. Because of this there is no `predecessor_account_id` available, since `signer_account_id` is not available, and it is impossible that this was called from another contract.